# Getting database ID of scaffold object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, scaffolding, rails-postgresql

I have a scaffold form Student with some fields like first_name, last_name, DOB, GPA, etc. and I want to be able to reference their database ID once they've been created and wondering what the best way to do this is. The migration class is called CreateStudents and the table of them is called :students so is there a way to reference the element of the students table as I iterate through it and display info for each student within it? By the way I'm using postgresql with rails 4.0.3 and ruby 2.0.0 if these make any difference. I'm able to use :students.each within my index html file but not sure how I can reference their ID number within the database.

Thanks

Comment: You mean display de students_id from the database?

Comment: so there is no datafield for ID within student, I want to display their database ID, or position within the database table.

Comment: I have answered the question. If it was helpful, don't forget to upvote it and if it was perfect, you can also accept it as the right answer :p

Comment: Please try to format your answers a little, so they're readable, not just a giant block of text. Paragraphs, we have them for a reason. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only do `student.id`. Even if you don't see the `id` field (or other field) in the `Student.rb`, if it exists in the database, you can access to it with the field name.

In a way of example i'm attaching an image of something like that but in `rails console` and my entity is called `user`

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to display the `id` field of `students` in `index.html.erb`:

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>

   <%= student.id %>  ## Display the id as this
    ......
<% end %>
```